# What's the space called if $V\in R^n$ is identical to $V+(a,a,\ldots,a)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, terminology

If $R^n$ has all $(a,a,\ldots,a)$ equivalent as zero elements where $a \in R$, what is this space topology called?

Comment: So, you are thinking about the quotient space of $\mathbb{R}^n/\{(a,\dots,a)\}$, which is just the quotient of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by a one-dimensional subspace?  I *believe* this space is isomorphic (both as a vector space and as a topological space) to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$.

Comment: Yes. It's $R^{n-1}$. But how to find/define the basis for such space? Can the basis have the equivalence as well?